# Type 'NSError' has no member 'errorWith' in swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift

On the following line:

```
  completionHandler(Result.failure(NSError.errorWith(text: "Can't download video")))
```

I get:

> Type 'NSError' has no member 'errorWith'

**What is the current alternative?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply means `NSError` doesn't have errorWith method. If you want to create `NSError` with any description, try this

```
let error = NSError(domain: "SomeErrorDomain", code: -2001 /* some error code */, userInfo: ["description": "Can't download video"])
```